# Alias field to existing key in Pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I am working with a legacy API and need to alias a response field to something that has an existing key. For example, the API response looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "model_name": "Survey",
        "logo": {
            "url": "foo"
        },
        "uuid": "79bea0f3-d8d2-4b05-9ce5-84858f65ff4b",
        "logo_url": "foo"
    }
]
```

and I would like the string `"foo"` in the response to be in the field `logo` – not as a nested object but just as the string itself. I have the following schema:

```
class Survey(UUIDIdentifiable):
    logo_url: str = Field(None, alias="logo")

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
```

but it doesn't appear to be working properly (I assume because the aliased key still exists in the response). I could of course just iterate through the responses and delete the one `logo` key:

```
for item in responses:
    del item["logo"]
```

but that feels a bit hacky to me. Is there a better way to do this with Pydantic?

Comment: Does the problem occur while reading the model or writing the model? There should be both `logo_url` and `logo` keys on the response?

Comment: There should only be a single `logo` key on the response with the string. I'm not quite sure where the problem occurs but I think it's on write, I have a simple test setup and the response from the mocked endpoint doesn't actually include a `logo` field right now

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `computed_field` and `Field(exlcude=True)`. Note also the `Config` class is [deprecated in Pydantic v2.0](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/config/)

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, computed_field

class Logo(BaseModel):
    url: str = ''


class Survery(BaseModel):
    logo: Logo = Field(exclude=True)
    
    @computed_field
    @property
    def logo_url(self) -> str:
        return self.logo.url

a = Survery(logo={'url': 'foo'})
a.model_dump()
#{'logo_url': 'foo'}
```

If I understand your updated requirements, you can achieve that with the `serilization_alias` and `validation_alias` attributes of `Field` with `AliasPath`:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, AliasPath

class Survery(BaseModel):
    logo_url: str = Field(
        ...,
        serialization_alias="logo",
        validation_alias=AliasPath('logo', 'url')
    )

a = Survery.model_validate({'logo': {'url': 'foo'}})
a.model_dump(by_alias=True)
# {'logo': 'foo'}
```

Comment: I would like the field name in the serialized response to be `logo` not `logo_url` e.g. `{'logo': 'foo'}` - sorry, that wasn't very clear in my original question. I will see about upgrading our Pydantic version!